# send_keys attribute in selenium does not insert text, but shows no error (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying unsuccessfully to insert text in a box with the attribute send_keys()

```
driver.get('https://www.carrefour.es/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='search-input']"))).send_keys('bolsa')
```

This is the HTML:

```
<input id="search-input" placeholder="Buscar en todo Carrefour" title="Buscar en Carrefour" type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" value="" class="search-input search-box">
```

I tried to clear input, insert with xpath, id, css selector. They all boild down to not showing any error, yet not displaying any word.

Comment: "A read-only input field cannot be modified "  Chances are there's some other action that needs to occur for this input field to accept input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user clicks on the search input box, the element is actually changing. You need to add explicit wait & then you should be able to input the text. I am able to enter text into the search box.

```
driver.get('https://www.carrefour.es/')
searchElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='search-input']")))

#This click should enable to input box

searchElement.click()

# Wait for the element

searchInput = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@inputmode= 'search']")))

searchInput.send_keys("Hi")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'search-button')]").click()
```